# 3d Graphics Library in source engine for macos

Tags: opengl, directx, 3d

what is the 3d Graphics Library in source engine for macos?(directx of opengl in half-life2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectX is a proprietary API by Microsoft, it is available on MS Windows and XBox only. OpenGL is crossplatform and it is available on almost every platform.

Edit: Thanks @erjot for your input.

Comment: besides windows there is xbox as well

Comment: Did they rewrote directX source-code of ValveSourceEngine to OpenGL?

Comment: I would guess that Valve is maintaining both a Direct3D back-end as well as a OpenGL back-end.

Comment: It actually is possible that they either adapted WINE to run the DirectX backend well (or adapted the DirectX backend to be ran by WINE) - from what I heard, this porting variant sometimes is cheaper to do than rewriting the rendering backend from scratch.